# Spring - DataBase initialization and deferred constraints

Tags: spring, hibernate, constraints

I have a problem with a database :

I am trying to init a fat db with a lot of constraints, with spring data jpa,  hibernate and data dummies.
When I lunch my api, the base is created, altered and data are inserted, with exceptions
I want to use deferred contraints, but I do not know how...
Is it possible with hibernate/spring ?

My application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:rgpdv2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/h2-data.sql
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the following Ticket hibernate does not have a way of handling deferred constraints yet:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2248

Moreover H2 does not support deferred checking too: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html

Maybe you could import your data as a SQL file?